# add data using a loop in 2d dictionary in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift2

i declare a 2d dictionary like below:

```
var dic:NSDictionary = [Int:[String:String]]()
```

Now, i want to insert data in a 2d dictionary using a loop. i stuck in doing this

sample dictionary view is

```
dic[0]
      - key value
      - key value
dic[1]
      - key vlaue
      - key value 
dic[2]
      - key value
      - key value
```

Comment: What's your issue, exactly?

Comment: Can you add the code that you have try

Comment: @AMomchilov actually i want to add key and value in 2d dictionary using loop, i got some answer and let me try on those but if u have better solution than those answer, please suggest me..... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vacawama mentions in his answer, there's no reason not to stick to native Swift types: use `Dictionary` rather than `NSDictionary`. This answer presents an alternative method of working with nested dictionaries.

#### Optional chaining and dictionary method `updateValue(_:forKey:)`

You can make use of `Dictionary`'s `updateValue(_:forKey:)` method to set or update the value for a particular key. I'm uncertain what you mean by *"in a loop"*, but below follows an example of using the `updateValue(_:forKey:)` for constructing the outer dictionary as well as the inner dictionaries (here, dummy dictionaries)

```
var dict = [Int:[String:String]]()

for outerKey in (0...3) {
    // reset/create a new inner dictionary
    dict.updateValue([:], forKey: outerKey)
    
    // update/add new key-value pair of inner dict
    for dummyKeyValuePairs in (1...2) {
        dict[outerKey]?.updateValue("Value\(dummyKeyValuePairs)",
                                    forKey: "Key\(dummyKeyValuePairs)")
    }
}

print(dict)
/* [2: ["Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2"], 
    0: ["Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2"], 
    1: ["Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2"], 
    3: ["Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2"]] */
```

If you'd like to add (or edit) another key-value-pair to one of your inner dictionaries, just make use of `updateValue(_:forKey:)` just as above:

```
dict[2]?.updateValue("NewValue", forKey: "NewKey")
   /*   \
       note that this optional chaining here means our
       updating/adding of inner dictionary key-value pairs
       is entirely performed as a side effect, where we
       never make use of the actual result of the expression */

print(dict)
/* [2: ["Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2", "NewKey": "NewValue"],
    0: ["Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2"],
    1: ["Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2"],
    3: ["Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2"]] */
```

---

W.r.t. your question of how to print the key value pairs of the dictionary, you could e.g. apply a nested `for ... in` approach:

```
for (outerKey, innerDict) in dict {
    print("Key-value pairs for outer dict key \(outerKey) follows:")
    for (key, value) in innerDict {
        print("\tkey: \(key), value: \(value)")
    }
}
/*  Key-value pairs for outer dict key 2 follows:
        key: Key2, value: Value2
        key: Key1, value: Value1
    Key-value pairs for outer dict key 0 follows:
        key: Key2, value: Value2
        key: Key1, value: Value1
    Key-value pairs for outer dict key 1 follows:
        key: Key2, value: Value2
        key: Key1, value: Value1
    Key-value pairs for outer dict key 3 follows:
        key: Key2, value: Value2
        key: Key1, value: Value1                  */
```

Note that dictionaries are unordered collection, hence the unordered output when printing above.

Comment: thanks for your help but if i want print those 2d dict data, what is the way? i use like :    for i in 0..<dict.count{
    for j in 0..<dict[i]?.count{
        for (key,value) in dict[i][j]!{
        
            print(i)
            print(j)
            print("enter")
            print(dict[j]!)
    
        }
    }
}

but it is not helping me

Comment: @Helper I edited the answer to include one example of how to print the content of the dictionaries. I would generally avoid explicit "index"(/key) access myself, if the only purpose is to print _all_ the content of the dictonaries. If you want content to be ordered, you might want to re-think the use of dictionaries (alternative: array of tuples).

Comment: thanks a lot its working .... but why the indexing is unsorted, i mean why it is first 2 why not 0

Comment: @Helper happy to help. I mention this in the last sentence of my answer: dictionaries are _unordered collections_ meaning they hold content in the form of key-value pairs, but they have no order of this content. If order is important to you, you might be better off using a different data structure, e.g. an array with tuple values.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you stick with Swift types for your dictionary and not use `NSDictionary`.  If you create a `[Int:[String:String]]` dictionary, you can pass that to a routine that takes an `NSDictionary` but you get all the advantages of Swift's type system.

When you insert into a multilevel dictionary, you need to make sure the inner dictionary exists before you try to add a value to it.  I have used the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to get the inner dictionary.  If `dict[key1]` returns `nil`, then there is no inner dictionary corresponding to the key, so create a dictionary with `[:]`.

```
var dict = [Int:[String:String]]()

func insert(inout dict: [Int:[String:String]], key1: Int, key2: String, value: String) {
    var inner = dict[key1] ?? [:]
    inner[key2] = value
    dict[key1] = inner
}

insert(&dict, key1: 1, key2: "hair", value: "brown")
print(dict)
```

> ```
> [1: ["hair": "brown"]]
> ```

```
insert(&dict, key1: 1, key2: "eyes", value: "green")
print(dict)
```

> ```
> [1: ["eyes": "green", "hair": "brown"]]
> ```

```
insert(&dict, key1: 0, key2: "hair", value: "black")
print(dict)
```

> ```
> [0: ["hair": "black"], 1: ["eyes": "green", "hair": "brown"]]
> ```

Comment: can u please help how i can do this using loop and again print the data using loop ............. thanks.

Comment: Edit your question to show some data you want inserted in the dictionary. What does the first key 0, 1, 2 represent? How would you know which key to use when inserting data?